# Python Regex and group function

Tags: python, regex

Hi trying to separate each of the expressions from the colon.  So want to obtain 'ss_vv', 'kk' and 'pp'.  But the two print expressions below give me 'v' and 'k', so getting parts only of each string.  Can anyone see what wrong here?

```
m0 = re.compile(r'([a-z]|_)+:([a-z]|_)+:([a-z]|_)+')
m1 = m0.search('ss_vv:kk:pp')
print m1.group(1)
print m1.group(2)
```

Comment: A simple split on `:` ?

Answer (score 4):

```
In [52]: m0 = re.compile(r'([a-z|_]+):([a-z|_]+):([a-z|_]+)')

In [53]: m1 = m0.search('ss_vv:kk:pp')

In [54]: print m1.group(1)
ss_vv

In [55]: print m1.group(2)
kk

In [56]: print m1.group(3)
pp
```

What my regex does:

```
([a-z|_]+):([a-z|_]+):([a-z|_]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GLOmQniLEruFOdRF)

What your regex does:

```
([a-z]|_)+:([a-z]|_)+:([a-z]|_)+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RMei9CVdMLW4aEkE)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regex for your case. You can just split on basis of ':' and get required output..

```
>>> a = 'ss_vv:kk:pp'
>>> b_list = a.split(':')
>>> b_list
['ss_vv', 'kk', 'pp']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

What are the other rules for the regular expression? based on your question, this regex would do:

```
m0 = re.compile(r'(.*):(.*):(.*)')
m1 = m0.search('ss_vv:kk:pp')
print m1.group(1)
print m1.group(2)
```

**UPDATE:**
as mentioned by @Jan in the comments, for efficient and better use of regex, you can modify it as

```
regex = r'([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+)'
m0 = re.compile(regex)
```

output:

```
ss_vv
kk
```

or by just splitting the string:

```
string = 'ss_vv:kk:pp'
parts = string.split(':')

print parts

outputs: ['ss_vv', 'kk', 'pp']
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I believe `[^:]*` would not work?

Comment: Not on ist own, of course. What I meant, is the difference between [`[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:\n]*`](https://regex101.com/r/dT2oT8/1) and [`(.*):(.*):(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/dT2oT8/2) - do you see the **significant** reduction in steps? The former needs 36, while the latter needs 284 (9 times!). My point is: the dot-star (`.*`) brings you down the line and then* backtracks* - which can be very ineffective sometimes. As a general rule of thumb I would say, try to be more specific and try to come to an end faster with regular expressions. Nevertheless, +1 for the splitting option here :)

Comment: oh... yes, I see your point.. that's very informative.. :) thanks!